# How to install MONyog in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm newbie to `ubuntu`, I wants to install MONyog.

And, I'm trying to install and download [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/MONyog-MySQL-Monitor-for-Linux/3000-2065_4-75707534.html), its download `tar.gz` format.

But I don't how install that,..`MONyog-5.5.8-0.x86_64.tar.gz`

After I complete the download and see **`README`**

its says like

```
===============================================================================
2. Configuring MONyog on Linux
===============================================================================
MONyog port and password are configurable through "MONyog.ini".

If MONyog was installed from the RPM package, MONyog.ini can be found in:
/usr/local/MONyog

If MONyog is extracted from the tarball (.tar.gz package), MONyog.ini 
can be found in the directory where MONyog was extracted.

The content of this file looks like:

[GENERAL]

port=5555
password=mypasswd

NOTE: MONyog should be stopped before editing this file, and restarted once
changes are saved.
```

And **`MONyog.ini`** looks like here,

```
[GENERAL]
Port=5555
Password=
Data_path=/home/ubuntu/Downloads/MONyog/bin/..//data
Registration_name=
Key=
Install_id=e1dbc993-3c5a-4869-984c-d5c04c07837f
```

I think its extracting

And extracting file is look here,`Home/MONyog`

try this only look like here,

```
ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ cd /home/ubuntu/Downloads
ubuntu@P3-SD1:~/Downloads$ sudo mv MONyog-5.5.8-0.x86_64.tar.gz ~
ubuntu@P3-SD1:~/Downloads$ cd ~
ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ tar -xf MONyog-5.5.8-0.x86_64.tar.gz
ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `.rpm` packages cannot be installed in Ubuntu. What are the contents in extracted folder?

Comment: @user301039, thanks for very first response.... what can i do now?

Comment: can you mention the content files inside the extracted folder?

Comment: @user301039, yes, your exactly right than after what can i do?

Comment: `.rpm` should be converted to `.deb` file and then install. so please mention the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I am installing the trial version only.

I've downloaded the MONyog trial version [here](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) (file name `MONyog-5.5.8-0.x86_64.tar.gz`) and moved it directly into my Home directory (`~`).

These are the commands I used:

```bsh
# extract the archive:
~$ tar -xf MONyog-5.5.8-0.x86_64.tar.gz

# navigate to the extracted folder and look at its contents:
~$ cd /home/ubuntu/MONyog
~/MONyog$ ls

bin           data    MONyog.ini  MONyog.lua  preferences.config  res
Counters.def  MONyog  MONyog.log  MONyog.mib  README              Udo.def

~/MONyog$ cd bin

~/MONyog/bin$ ls
MONyog  MONyog-bin

# try running the executable:
~/MONyog/bin$ ./MONyog
Usage: ./MONyog {start|stop|restart|reload|status}

~/MONyog/bin$ ./MONyog start
MONyog is already running...
```

Check its web interface in your browser:

```
http://localhost:5555/
http://localhost:5555/mlogin.html
```

Comment: This was a great start, sadly the startup script doesn't appear to be fully compatible with systemd that came in somewhere in the 15.x series and is used in 16.04 and will be in 18.04 as well. In order to get it working there we ended up copying a systemd unit file we found on the web, I'll submit the contents as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://forums.webyog.com/forums/topic/running-monyog-with-systemd-on-debian-jessie/) and [here](https://elhombrequereventodeinformacion.wordpress.com/2017/11/15/systemd-unit-for-monyog/) this is a valid systemd unit file for MONyog.

```
[Unit]
Description=Webyog MONyog Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=monyog
LimitNOFILE=262144
ExecStart=/usr/local/MONyog/bin/MONyog-bin
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```